# how to open existing file like .docx, .txt, .pptx through java?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to open a file through java.

I can open Office itself like this

```
     try {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\EXCEL.EXE");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I want to open files directly from java.

Comment: Your title and question don't match very well. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Do you want to read the contents ?

Comment: I want to open "myfile.pptx" through java
for example: I have 1 button call "myfile" so when I click, it will open "myfile.pptx"

but I don't know how to write those code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the associated program to open a file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989500/find-the-associated-program-to-open-a-file-using-java)

Comment: sorry because I am not good at English

Comment: Edit your question pls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,

```
    try{

        if ((new File("c:\\your_file.pdf")).exists()) {

            Process p = Runtime
               .getRuntime()
               .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\\your_file.pdf");
            p.waitFor();

        } else {

            System.out.println("File does not exist");

        }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

or you can do it this with `Desktop.open(File)`,

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```

You can open pptx (and more) files as well with this approach.

Comment: Desktop.isDesktopSupported() cannot find symbol.

Comment: sikander @ you are amazing. It works perfectly (the first one).
but the second one I got error "cannot find symbol desktop"

Comment: oh I found the reason why it's error now...
thank you again @sikander

Comment: good to hear, share your found reason so that it helps others in the future.