# Generating and Opening a PDF file

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF file and open it after generation in a new window so that users can print it. I have below code which generates the pdf and saves it on the disk, but having trouble opening it.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld-Table.pdf"));
document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));

table.addCell(cell1);
table.addCell(cell2);
table.addCell(cell3);

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

What can I add here so that it opens the PDF file?

Comment: Perhaps you could open it using Java instead of iText: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20494950/892536

Comment: @tehDorf That is correct. Consider making that an answer (or maybe we should mark the question as a possible duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to open existing file like .docx, .txt, .pptx through java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494773/how-to-open-existing-file-like-docx-txt-pptx-through-java)

Comment: iText is not a PDF viewer, and the fact you used that lib to generate your PDF file is irrelevant here, that's why I removed the [tag:itext] tag. It's more of a generic [tag:java] question, thus the tag I added.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and suggestions. May be I did not make myself clear enough here. My whole intention was to ask whether I can open this pdf instead of saving to disk?